# Authorizing wikimedia API usage: rest-read-denied error

Tags: wikipedia-api

I'm trying to fetch a decent number of API URLs like `https://api.wikimedia.org/core/v1/wikipedia/en/file/File%3AFlag%20of%20Madison%20Heights%2C%20Michigan.svg`.

I have [signed up for an API key as described in the instructions](https://api.wikimedia.org/wiki/Documentation/Getting_started/Authentication#Personal_API_tokens).

However, when I issue my requests with the `Authorization: Bearer [long JWT Access Token goes here]` header, I just get `{"error":"rest-read-denied","httpCode":403,"httpReason":"Forbidden"}` back.

If I omit the `Authorization` header, then I do get a good response, but am severely rate limited.

The [API Portal](https://api.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:AppManagement) says that my API key is approved. I have tried resetting the secret, and have tried creating a separate one, I have inspected the exact headers sent by using `curl -v` and I can see the Authorization header in there and it looks correct (diffed it with the access token).

If I modify the token, then I get a different error message: `{"httpCode":401,"httpReason":"Jwt verification fails"}` so clearly my token is passed in correctly and it's a permissions issue with my API key. I have tried both a key with read only permission, and a key with both read & edit permissions, but no dice.

The example cURL request in the signup instruction also fails with a `rest-read-denied` error:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $AccessToken" \
https://api.wikimedia.org/core/v1/wikipedia/en/page/Earth/bare
```

!?!?

Comment: Have you tried the troubleshooting guide? https://api.wikimedia.org/wiki/Documentation/Getting_started/Authentication#Troubleshooting

Comment: That did it, thanks! I swear that section wasn’t there when I wrote the question… ;)

Comment: @Jxtps As somebody who is receiving the same error, I was wondering if you could share the exact steps that you took to resolve it? The troubleshooting guide is very general and does not fix the problem for me.

Comment: I just logged into the relevant wikimedia project and then it started recognizing my API key.